# Fetching data from a different worksheet in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to source data from a separate sheet in excel but the second reference to `Ws_Names` brings up Runtime Error 1004. How would I correctly source values for a range from another sheet?

```
Dim Ws_Names As Worksheet
Set Ws_Names = Worksheets("Names")
        
Dim Ws_Data As Worksheet
Set Ws_Data = Worksheets("Data")
    
Dim SubTechs As Long, Names_range As Range
    
SubTechs = Ws_Names.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'this works
    
Set Names_range = Ws_Names.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(SubTechs, 2)) 'this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you don't put a leading reference it assumes Activesheet

What

```
Set Names_range = Ws_Names.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(SubTechs, 2)) 'this doesn't work
```

Actually says is, and your current activesheet isn't Ws_Names

```
Set Names_range = Ws_Names.Range(Activesheet.Cells(1, 1), Activesheet.Cells(SubTechs, 2))
```

So the solution is

```
Set Names_range = Ws_Names.Range(Ws_Names.Cells(1, 1), Ws_Names.Cells(SubTechs, 2))
```